# Cannot Convert Type List() to Custom Class Type in C# Razor foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of data consists of MainMenus and SubMenus,  MainMenus where ParentID =0 like the following example:-
[image: MainMenus and SubMenus combined]

I have read the above data using Stored Procedures  and Joining Three Tables which are
MainMenu
SubMenu
UserPermission

First selecting MainMenus and Joining them to UserPermission and filtering only those MainMenus which the current user has a permission to.
Then combining (Union) 
Selecting SubMenus and Joining them to UserPermission and filtering only those SubMenus which the current user has a permission to.
Now, I've the above tabular result set. I have got that tabular result set by using

```
public DataTable getUserMenus(string userID)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Proc_GetUserMenus", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dataTable);

            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

When I Returned my Desired Result set, I converted DataTable to IEnumerable by using the following code

```
public IEnumerable<GeneratedMenus> ConvertToGeneratedMenus(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            yield return new GeneratedMenus
            {
                MenuID = Convert.ToInt32(row["MenuID"]),
                MenuName = Convert.ToString(row["MenuName"]),
                ActionName = Convert.ToString(row["ActionName"]),
                ControllerName = Convert.ToString(row["ControllerName"]),
                ParentID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ParentID"]),

            };


        }
    }
```

GeneratedMenus is class I have created to Hold MainMenus and SubMenus, and it is look like

```
public class GeneratedMenus
    {
        public int MenuID { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
    }
```

In the HomeController Index ActionResult I have a Code to populate ViewBag.MenuList Property

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        ViewBag.MenusList =   da.ConvertToGeneratedMenus(da.getUserMenus("MyUserID")).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

DataAccess is a class where ConvertToGeneratedMenus() and getUserMenus reside. And I'm using classic ADO.NET ConnectionString for SQL Server Database Connection.

The Last Section is _Layout.cshtml  Partial View which in turn I have the following C# Razor Code for displaying the MainMenus and SubMenus Respectively

```
@if (ViewBag.MenusList != null)
                {                                                                   
                    foreach (MainMenu  mainMenu in ViewBag.MenusList)
                    {
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                @mainMenu.MenuName
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                @foreach (SubMenu subMenu in ViewBag.MenuList)
                                {
                                    if (subMenu.ParentID == mainMenu.MainMenuID)
                                    {
                                      <li>
                                      @Html.ActionLink(
                                      @subMenu.MenuName, 
                                      @subMenu.ActionName, 
                                      @subMenu.ControllerName)
                                      </li>
                                    }

                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }

                }
```

The Error I'm receiving is:-
Cannot convert type 'DataAccess.GeneratedMenus' to 'MainMenu'
So, the Question is what is wrong with my code? Or can you please tell me a better idea to modify my code to make this job done?
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Note: MainMenu, SubMenu,UserPermission  are  Generated Model Classes at the time of EDMX (Entity Data Model)  Database Generating Wizzard, but GeneratedMenus is Custom class I declared my Self.

Comment: please post only relevant code

Comment: Your `ViewBag.MenusList` is `IEnumerable<GeneratedMenus>` so `foreach (MainMenu  mainMenu in ViewBag.MenusList)` needs to be `foreach (GeneratedMenus menu in ViewBag.MenusList)` (`IEnumerable<GeneratedMenus>` is not `IEnumerable<MainMenu >`) - ditto for `foreach (SubMenu subMenu in ViewBag.MenuList)`

Comment: This worked for me for the first foreach statement, but the second foreach with GeneratedMenus produces an error Object reference is not set to an instance of an object. may be ViewBag.MenusList becomes null at the second foreach, any suggestions?

Comment: Your nested foreach loops don't really make any sense - why you looping through the same list twice?

Comment: To select the MainMenus then the SubMenus, what you suggest Stephen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the above question by modifying some of my code
In HomeController Index Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        //Getting all generated Menus and SubMenus
        var AllMenus = da.ConvertToGeneratedMenus(da.generateUserMenus("UserID")).ToList();
        //Getting MainMenus (where ParentID==0 in my case)
        var mainMenus = AllMenus.Where(mm => mm.ParentID == 0).ToList();
        //Getting SubMenus (where ParentID != 0 in my case)
        var subMenus = AllMenus.Where(sm => sm.ParentID != 0).ToList();

        //Assigning my MainMenus and SubMenus to two ViewBag properties(MainMenusList,SubMenuList) respectively 
        ViewBag.MainMenusList = mainMenus;
        ViewBag.SubMenuList = subMenus;

        return View();
    }
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml file

```
@if (ViewBag.MainMenusList != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataAccess.GeneratedMenus mainMenu in ViewBag.MainMenusList)
                    {
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                @mainMenu.MenuName
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             @foreach (DataAccess.GeneratedMenus subMenu in ViewBag.SubMenuList)
                                {
                                    if (subMenu.ParentID == mainMenu.MenuID)
                                    {
                                      <li>
                                      @Html.ActionLink(
                                      @subMenu.MenuName, 
                                      @subMenu.ActionName, 
                                      @subMenu.ControllerName)
                                      </li>
                                    }

                                }
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }

                }
```

Although my inner loop makes un-necessary repetitions, still it generates the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a model which represents what you want to display

```
public class Menu
{
  public Menu()
  {
    Children = new List<Menu>();
  }
  public int MenuID { get; set; }
  public string MenuName { get; set; }
  public string ActionName { get; set; }
  public string ControllerName { get; set; }
  // The collection of sub menus associated with the menus
  public List<Menu> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

and in the view

```
@model List<Menu>
....
<ul>
  @foreach(Menu main in Model)
  {
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@main.MenuName</a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach (Menu sub in main.Children)
        {
          <li>@Html.ActionLink(sub.MenuName, subMenu.ActionName, subMenu.ControllerName)</li>
        }
      </ul>
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

And in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<Menu> model = new List<Menu>();
  // populate the collection (i.e. where parentID is null)
  // populate the sub menus for each menu item
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke. Your answer works, in my case the model classes MainMenu and SubMenu are auto generated from EDMX generate database wizard, any change i make to those generated classes will be overwritten if the code is regenerated. I will post the way i solved in my case as another answer, and I accepted yours.

Comment: You should always use view models (not the data models) to represent what you need in a view. [What is viewmodel in mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: I will consider that. Thanks